# Constructing a instance variable pyparsing matcher from class variable elements

Tags: python, oop, deep-copy, pyprocessing

With [`pyparsing`](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) I construct a
complex matcher object which is suppose to match slightly different
things depending on a instantiation flag. Here a (simplified) example:

```
class MyMatcher():

    def __init__( self, special_flag = False):
        self.special_flag = special_flag

        a = pp.Word(pp.alphas)('A')
        if self.special_flag:
            b = pp.Word(pp.alphas)('B')
        else:
            b = pp.Word(pp.nums)('B')
        c = pp.Word(pp.alphas)('C')
        # d = ...
        # e = ...
        # ...

        self.expr = (a + b | b ) + pp.Optional(c) # + ...

    def parse(self, s):
        return self.expr.parseString(s, parseAll=True)
```

`a`, `b`, `c`,.... are *class* variables, so that I can reference them
in `expr` just like that and do not have to prefix them with the
instance reference `self` (like in `self.a`). `expr` has to be an
*instance* variable because different instantiations of `MyMatcher`
have to match different things.

The above example works:

```
mymTrue = MyMatcher(True)
mymFalse = MyMatcher(False)
print (mymTrue.parse("alpha aaaa alpha"))
print (mymFalse.parse("alpha 777 alpha"))
```

returns as expected:

```
['alpha', 'aaaa', 'alpha']
['alpha', '777', 'alpha']
```

My worry is: Does this work even for very complex matchers with lots
of (nested) `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, etc... ? Or phrased differently: **Is
the full logic *(deep-)copied* from the class variables to the instance
object `expr`, so that it doesn't matter that the `a`, `b` and `c`
get overwritten on the next `MyMatcher` object creation?**

Or if this is a problem, is there another way to create varying
matchers with short and beautiful construction like `(a + b | b ) +
pp.Optional(c)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables `a`, `b`, `c`,.... are **not** class variables; they are local variables in the `__init__` method. References to these variables will be kept alive as long as needed. (See in the Python documentation [Scopes and Namespaces in Classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces).)